# Android Picasso - how do I know memory issue is fixed?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using a RecyclerView with images (approx 140 items in the list).

I had memory issues before so I removed the images from the view completely, before I put the APP live.

Now I am using Picasso to load the images, but before I upload this new version to the PlayStore, I'd like to be confident that this has fixed the memory issue?  The new phone I'm using to test this on has a lot more memory than my previous phone, so I cannot reproduce the original problem anymore.

I am resizing my image to match my screen width.

Comment: Look at what the profiler is telling you or/and make some stress tests

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler
you can find the heap and memory details from profiler.
Connect your device to PC, start android studio and navigate to profiler view. Click on App icon and you will be seeing the logs

Comment: Should I be adding some sort of limit of the memory Picasso uses?